# Div.scrollTop prematurely scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am building a chat system and I am trying to animate text when appended to the `div` "server-output", but also keep the div scrolled down so that the animation can be seen.

```
function output(name, msg, flt, clss){
    var string = ' \
        <div class="'+flt+'">'+name+':</div> \
        <div class="'+clss+'"> '+msg+'</div> \
    ';
    $(string).appendTo('.server-output').hide();
    $(".server-output").scrollTop($(".server-output")[0].scrollHeight); // Scrolls to bottom of div
    $('.'+ clss + ':last, .'+flt+':last').show('fast');
}
```

This works fine for text that only takes up one line, but when it takes up 2 or more the scroll event does not scroll down enough.

Is there a way to hide elements while keeping their structure (like an invisible or something?)

OR

Is there some better way to do this? The way it is coded right now, it's almost a chicken and egg problem. I can't scroll till the element exists, but for the element's animation to be seen, I have to scroll below it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
function output(name, msg, flt, clss){
    var string = ' \
        <div class="'+flt+'">'+name+':</div> \
        <div class="'+clss+'"> '+msg+'</div> \
    ';
    $(string).appendTo('.server-output').css("opacity", 0);
    $(".server-output").scrollTop($(".server-output")[0].scrollHeight); // Scrolls to bottom of div
    $('.'+ clss + ':last, .'+flt+':last').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
}
```

It uses opacity and a fade to transition the new text, which should resolve the issues with spacing when hiding it and then showing it later.

Also, just a suggestion, you can cache the added element as a local variable and reference it through that, rather than doing a jQuery parse later on...

```
function output(name, msg, flt, clss){
    var string = ' \
        <div class="'+flt+'">'+name+':</div> \
        <div class="'+clss+'"> '+msg+'</div> \
    ';
    var $string = $(string).appendTo('.server-output');
    $string.css("opacity", 0);
    $(".server-output").scrollTop($(".server-output")[0].scrollHeight); // Scrolls to bottom of div
    $string.animate({ opacity: 1 }, 500);
}
```

Comment: just be careful with `opacity`, as its support is somehow limited in older and non-standard browsers - http://caniuse.com/css-opacity

Comment: Of course, but you can say that about anything (including jQuery!)  It looks safe enough to me... http://caniuse.com/css-opacity

Comment: really depends on the targeted audience - old mobile phones, old opera, old Android, different countries are outdated differently :) but +1 for the solution nonetheless

Comment: HEY the second function worked! and better than expected. It allowed me to get rid of a little bit of hacky nonsense I was doing some other place. +1 Archer. That was a bulls eye.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're hiding the `.server-output` element, jQuery can't correctly calculate its dimensions and thus will scroll to an incorrect position.

What you can try is to apply `.css('visibility', 'hidden')` and then show the element via `.css('visibility', 'visible')` again. This should calculate your `scrollTop` position correctly.

```
function output(name, msg, flt, clss){
    var string = ' \
        <div class="'+flt+'">'+name+':</div> \
        <div class="'+clss+'"> '+msg+'</div> \
    ';
    $(string).appendTo('.server-output').css('visibility' 'hidden');
    $(".server-output").scrollTop($(".server-output")[0].scrollHeight); // Scrolls to bottom of div
    $('.'+ clss + ':last, .'+flt+':last').css('visibility' 'visible');
}
```

Comment: @Archer what you mean by that?

Comment: He has `.show("fast")` - that's not the same as just making it visible

Comment: you're right... that would require storing old height, then animating it to the new height once it becomes visible, or changing opacity - depends on what does the OP really needs, however - as this was not part of the question I did not find it necessary to complicate matters

Comment: It is part of the question - it's in the code at the top of the page :p

Comment: actually, now that I think of it - simply doing `.hide().css('visibility' 'visible').show('fast')` should do the job, as the scroll position should already be correct at that point - given the element is not positioned at the very bottom of document

Comment: Unfortunately, I got the same result with that snippet. I was thinking  about calculating the height the new element would be and scroll by that much. Can you scroll past where the scroll bar ends if you do it in code?

Comment: `show()` doesn't affect visibility at all.  Once you set it to visible you can see it and show won't have any effect.

Comment: @M1Reeder I'd strongly recommend setting opacity to 0 when you add the new text and then fading it in.  It will still take up the required space, and will give you a nice transition effect.